# SQL Query, take last row to fill new column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | company_id | from_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 345 | 200601 |
| 112 | 345 | 200603 |
| 112 | 379 | 200703 |
| 113 | 338 | 200808 |
| 113 | 309 | 200912 |
| 113 | 391 | 201009 |
| 114 | 318 | 200910 |

And I want my table to look like this:

| id | company_id | from_dt | to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 345 | 200601 | NULL |
| 112 | 345 | 200603 | 200703 |
| 112 | 379 | 200703 | NULL |
| 113 | 338 | 200808 | 200912 |
| 113 | 309 | 200912 | 201009 |
| 113 | 391 | 201009 | NULL |
| 114 | 318 | 200910 | NULL |

I just can't quite figure out the best way to format an SQL query to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    LAG(from_dt, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY from_dt DESC) AS to_dt
FROM orig_table
```

assumes that the from_dt is of type integer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the window function `LEAD()` :

```
SELECT *, LEAD(from_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY from_dt) AS to_dt
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id, from_dt
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vUTpSuUs)